# How to break out of an infinite loop with a Tkinter button?

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, interrupt, python-2.x

I am working in a program where I use `Tkinter` for the UI. I am writing a code to play an audio repeatedly. I am using `pygame.mixer.music()` for playing audio.

In the UI I created two buttons ("Start" and "Stop"). I attached a method which contains the loop structure to the start button, so that when the Start button is pressed the loop will be executed and starts playing audio repeatedly. Now I don't know how to attach the Stop button. Like, when Stop button is pressed the control should exit the loop. Can I use interrupts or some other thing like that? Iam totaly new to the concept of interrupts. To proceed with that, help me with what kind of interrupt, what is the library for that, etc. If not please help me how to proceed with the stop button.

Here is my code:

```
from pygame import *
from Tkinter import *
import time
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x200")
root.title("sampler")
m=1
n=1
mixer.init()
def play():

    while m==1:

        print 'playing'
        mixer.music.load('audio 1.mp3')
        mixer.music.play()
        time.sleep(n)

start = Button(root, text="play", command = play)
start.pack()
stop = Button(root, text="Stop")
stop.pack()
mainloop()
```

`n` defines how long the audio should be played for each loop.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't exactly support interrupts, the closest thing would probably be some sort of signal handler, which are supported via its [`signal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#module-signal) library. However they may not work well with Tkinter (or `pygame`), so I don't think that would be a good approach—and they're not really necessary anyway because what you want to do can be handled within Tkinter's `mainloop()`.

Although it may seem somewhat complex, the way I would suggest implementing it would be to encapsulate most of the playing control functionality within a single Python `class`. This will reduce the use of global variables, which will make the program easier to debug and develop further (because of the many advantages of Object-Oriented Programming — aka as [**OOP**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)).

Below illustrates what I mean. Note, I'm using Python 3, so had to make a few additional changes to your code in order for it would work with that version. I'm not sure, but this version ought to work in Python 2, as well, except you'll need to change the `import` of the Tkinter module as indicated.

```
from pygame import *
from tkinter import *  # Change to "from Tkinter import *" for Python 2.x.

class PlayController(object):
    def __init__(self, mixer, music_filename, polling_delay):
        self.mixer = mixer
        self.music_filename = music_filename
        self.polling_delay = polling_delay  # In milliseconds.
        self.playing = False

    def play(self):
        if self.playing:
            self.stop()
        self.mixer.music.load(self.music_filename)
        self.mixer.music.play(-1)  # -1 means to loop indefinitely.
        self.playing = True
        root.after(self.polling_delay, self.check_status)  # Start playing check.

    def stop(self):
        if self.playing:
            self.mixer.music.stop()
            self.playing = False

    def check_status(self):
        if self.playing:
            print('playing')
        root.after(self.polling_delay, self.check_status)  # Repeat after delay.

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x200")
root.title("Sampler")
mixer.init()

play_control = PlayController(mixer, 'tone.wav', 1000)
Button(root, text="Play", command=play_control.play).pack()
Button(root, text="Stop", command=play_control.stop).pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you dude.this goes great but here, i needed to print some message repeatedly for each time the loop repeats the audio.thus the method of looping alone the audio like what you did does not support with what i need.Thank you for your valuable time you spent to help me

Comment: dani: That can be fixed relatively easy by using the universal widget method `after()`. Here some [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) on how to use it. I've modified my answer to show how it could be used to do what you want (I think).

Comment: bro,i checked with the documentation of after() method but i cannot understand it.can you give me some example programs in which the method is used.thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, here's a couple: [Cannot delete tkinter object on canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49096077/cannot-delete-tkinter-object-on-canvas) and [Animating an object to move in a circular path in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814297/animating-an-object-to-move-in-a-circular-path-in-tkinter). It's often used to do animation in `tkinter`. The basic idea is that during calls to `mainloop()`, the designated function will be called after the specified delay...and to make that happen over-and-over, the function usually calls `after` again itself so that the process repeats.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a command to your button... `stop = Button(root, text="Stop", command=stop)`

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a stop command probably wont work because the way your infinite loop is structured, you can't interact with the tkinter interface while play is clicked. Try restructuring your program like this:

```
from Tkinter import *
from pygame import *
import time
import threading

switch = True
root = Tk()
n = 1
mixer.init()
root.geometry("1000x200")
root.title("sampler")


def play():
    def run():
        while switch:
            print 'playing'
            mixer.music.load('audio 1.mp3')
            mixer.music.play()
            time.sleep(n)
            if not switch:
                break

    thread = threading.Thread(target=run)
    thread.start()


def switch_on():
    global switch
    switch = True
    play()


def switch_off():
    global switch
    switch = False


def kill():
    root.destroy()


onbutton = Button(root, text="Play", command=switch_on)
onbutton.pack()
offbutton = Button(root, text="Stop", command=switch_off)
offbutton.pack()
killbutton = Button(root, text="Kill", command=kill)
killbutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This way the tkinter buttons are running on separate threads, so while one is looping you can still interact with the other.

Comment: Thank you dude for your valuable suggestion,Now the issue of hanging out(not responding) is solved with what you gave.But ,still the loop does not exit when the stop button is pressed. And with the kill button, the system closes the window but the process is still running behind untill i close the shell.IS there any way to solve this.